# Why does Edward prefer to use his automail over Alchemy?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

So I've been watching *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*, and I didn't understand why Edward didn't use Alchemy every time he encountered enemies?
Like the fight with Number 48 in Research Lab 5, and the first fight with Scar, and etc. He just uses his right automail arm like a short sword, and we all know its not very effective to fight long ranged enemies. Alchemy definitely seems stronger, but why doesn't he use it?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga.SE! Seems like you have two distinct and pertinent questions here. It would be better if you split them into two separate questions. Happy answering/asking :)

Comment: need answer plss

Comment: I don't know whether that's correct, but it's most likely faster. Using alchemy means that you need to "clap" your hands, which means loss of important time. That is also noted by Mustang when he tries to fire at Father after he was blinded.

Comment: What about when he uses alchemy on his automail?

Answer (score 7):

He's trained in martial art by his master, Izumi Curtis. So he's definitely confident in his close combat ability. As to why he uses it over alchemy, you don't think he's just going to rely on alchemy all the time do you? He can adapt to different combat situation, and be more unpredictable if he can switch fighting style. Also his automail blade looks cool.

Answer (score 3):

Ed uses his martial abilities to create openings for him to use alchemy. If he outright use alchemy, the enemy would have already known what to do with him. Besides, alchemy is a really loud fighting style when used straight offensively and Ed, most of the time, don't want wanton destruction as much as possible. Ed uses alchemy discretely in some cases too (brittling Greed's armor) but even then alchemy still creates those flashy lights.